# Getting and parsing webpage from Internet on C# or C++

Tags: c#, c++, html

I'm making a WinForms project on C#/C++ (depending on the best way I could find to reach my goal, language could be changed). I need to get a page from website and parse it to get some information. I'm a very beginner in web programming with Visual C#/C++ and all the answers I found here are too complicated for me as a beginner. Could you help me to tell which standart classes should I use for getting page from Internet in some form and how to parse it then. I would be very pleased if you have any code examples, cause as I wrote above I have no experience in web coding and have no time to learn every term in detail. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at System.Net.HttpWebRequest class, and HtmlAgilityPack (an open source library) to do your parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use c# to download the specific webpage then do the analysis, an code example of downloading:

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

string result = null;
string url = "http://www.devtopics.com";
WebResponse response = null;
StreamReader reader = null;

try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( url );
    request.Method = "GET";
    response = request.GetResponse();

    ContentType contentType = new ContentType(response.ContentType);
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(contentType.CharSet);

    reader = new StreamReader( response.GetResponseStream(), encoding);
    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // handle error
  MessageBox.Show( ex.Message );
}
finally
{
  if (reader != null)
      reader.Close();
  if (response != null)
      response.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this project '[here](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)' and their code examples '[here](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples)'